# let $p$ be a real non-constant polynomial, prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1} e^{2\pi i n p(x)}dx=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

let $p$ be a real non-constant polynomial, prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1} e^{2\pi i n p(x)}dx=0$.

The inside it bounded by $1$ and so we can use DCT, I just do not know how to show the inside converges to $0$.

Comment: @Clayton Forgot to mention is it non constant! sorry

Comment: There's no DCTing oscillatory integrals. You can check [Van der Corput's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_lemma_(harmonic_analysis)) from Stein's Harmonic Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that for any strictly monotonic function of class $C^1$ and any open interval $I\subset[0,1]$
 we have 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{I} e^{in f(x)}\,dx = 0$$
due to the substitution $x=f^{-1}(u)$ and the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.
 Polynomials over compact intervals are $C^1$ and piecewise-monotonic.

---

Numerical experiments seem to support the claim that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(2\pi i n p(x)\right)\,dx = O\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/d}}\right) $$
where $d$ is the minimum degree of the monomials appearing in $p(x)-p(0)$.

Comment: The idea is nice but it is not obvious to me as to why $\frac  1 {f'(f^{-1}(x)}$ is integrable in an interval $[a,b]$ where $f'$ may vanish at the end points.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: the endpoints do not matter much, $$ \int_{[a,b]}=\int_{(a,b)}$$ I've put the word *open* in the description of the interval $I$.

Comment: I am talking about application of Riemann Lebesgue Lemma. You do need integrability to apply the lemma, right?

Comment: The derivative of the inverse function of $f(x)$ is integrable by construction. Also, we may just choose a different strategy for the set over which the function is approximately constant, i.e. $|f'(x)|\leq\varepsilon$. The point is this region shrinks to zero when $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Hi Jack.  This is only semi-relatedly ... If $f$ is monotonic only, is it true that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(x) \frac{\sin(kx)}{x}\,dx=\frac\pi2 f(0^+)?$$That is, we don't have the usual piecewise smoothness condition for application of the Fourier Inversion Theorem.  If $f$ were piecewise smooth, then the FIT holds and the aforementioned limit ia correct.  If $f$ is merely monotonic, is the limit even guaranteed to exist?

Comment: @MarkViola: in such a case the convolution $\tilde{f}(x)$ between $f(x)$ and a Jackson kernel is both smooth and monotonic, so by estimating the integral with $f(x)$ being replaced by $f(x)-\tilde{f}(x)$ I would guess the answer is still affirmative, maybe provided that the jump points do not accumulate toward zero.

Comment: @r9m: no, it's correct. For $p(x)=x+x^2$ the decay is of the $\frac{1}{n}$-type, for instance.

Comment: I don't have a software for numerical verification, did you check the cases where $p^{(d-1)}$ (the $(d-1)$ th derivative) has zero in $(0,1)$ .. $d$ being the degree of the polynomial ..

Comment: @r9m: nice question, that almost makes material for a follow-up. I haven't actually checked cases in which $p(x)$ has multiple zeroes or many stationary points in $[0,1]$, I will.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Could you elaborate why you need to only check it for monotonic functions? And why the substitution is legal? To my knowledge you can only substitute injective absolutely continuous functions.

Comment: @2132123 Polynomials are 'piecewise' injective and smooth. Split the integral into disjoint intervals where $P$ is strictly monotone (there is finitely many such intervals) and make the suggested change of variable.